# Removable Discontinuity can someone explain this?

Tags: calculus

What exactly is a removable discontinuity? If f(a) for some function f(x) is not defined but the limit as f(x) approaches a exists then does that make a a removable discontinuity? [image: Picture]

Like in this picture x=-3 is not defined but the limit as x approaches -3 exists and is equal to -10. So this means that as x approaches -3 f(x) approaches -10 but my question in this example is how do we it looks exactly perfectly like this? Like that hole fits perfectly and completes the linear line but how do I know that's true? Why can't it be a bit above the line or something?

Comment: The hole has been visually placed on the line because the missing point it represents has its limit on that line... it as a graphical decision. Sometimes you’ll see - if the function is defined at the discontinuity - the hole placed above

Comment: Okay but how do I know it's exactly on that line? what if the limit evaluated to like -11 and I was trying to sketch this function if I would've drawn the exact same thing it would be inaccurate

Comment: Because $-3-7=-10$

Comment: "Like that hole fits perfectly and completes the linear line but how do I know that's true? Why can't it be a bit above the line or something?" is not really a mathematical statement. You can, of course, define a function so that x=-3 maps to any other value either. What makes -10 special is it makes the function continuous.